# Is jQuery.parseJSON able to process all valid json?

Tags: jquery, json

This piece of valid json (it has been generated using php's json_encode):

```
{"html":"form is NOT valid<form id=\"articleform\" enctype=\"application\/x-www-form-urlencoded\" method=\"post\" action=\"\"><dl class=\"zend_form\">\n<dt id=\"title-label\">&nbsp;<\/dt>\n<dd id=\"title-element\">\n<input type=\"text\" name=\"title\" id=\"title\" value=\"Artikel K\"><\/dd>\n<dt id=\"articleFormSubmitted-label\">&nbsp;<\/dt>\n<dd id=\"articleFormSubmitted-element\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"articleFormSubmitted\" value=\"1\" id=\"articleFormSubmitted\"><\/dd>\n<dt id=\"submit-label\">&nbsp;<\/dt><dd id=\"submit-element\">\n<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Bewaar artikel\" onclick=\"this.value='Bezig...';\"><\/dd><\/dl><\/form><script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\t $(\"#articleform\").submit(function(){\n $.post(\"\/admin\/ajax\/contenttree\/node\/9\/ajaxtarget\/ajaxContainer\", $(\"#articleform\").serialize(), function(html){$(\"#ajaxContainer\").html(html);} );\n\t\t return false;\n\t });\n\n <\/script>","newNodeName":""}
```

is giving

```
jQuery.parseJSON(data)
```

and me a hard time.

With this piece of code:

```
alert('start');
alert(data);
jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert('stop');
```

I get a message start and then the data (jsonstring above) is shown. The message "stop" never appears.

When I use this json:

```
{"html":"test","newNodeName":""}
```

The message stop eventually appears.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/admin/ajax/contenttree/node/" + (node.id).replace("node_", ""),
      success: function(data){

      //this message appears
      alert("succes");

      //this gives undefined
      alert(data.html);

      var result = $.parseJSON(data);

      //this message never appears
      alert("after parse");

        $("#ajaxContainer").html(result.html);
      }
    });
```

I've verified that my first big chunk of json is valid. Why isn't it processed by `jQuery.parseJSON`
Are there any special characters that don't go well with json?

Comment: How is this json coming down to the client?

Comment: Via $.ajax.  The ajax-response itself is the result of a php-array that is processed by php_encode.

Comment: Don't shoot me, we're looking for errors, right? There's a missing semicolon after `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` in the above. It doesn't matter if it's followed by a newline (as it is in your quoted text) because of semicolon insertion and so is very unlikely to be the problem, but if (for instance) the code you're actually running is being minified/compressed/packed, it would be a problem. So, just mentioning.

Comment: A semicolon was indeed missing in the example above (i've corrected it now).  In my code on the server the semicolon was there.

Comment: As shown, you are trying to parse an object. JSON would look like `'{"html":"for....'` - so either your example is mispoken or you are trying to use a hammer to drive a screw. ;-)

Comment: The problem lies elsewhere, the example above works fine (with jQuery 1.4.1 and 1.4.2; that's all I tested); see the test page and data in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566644/is-jquery-parsejson-able-to-process-all-valid-json/2566689#2566689

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for my problem.  In my question you'll find that I tried to pass the html inside an array with the key `html`. In the javascript-code I tried to get the html using

```
jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(data.html);
```

When I renamed the key `htmlstring`  the `parseJSON`-function worked fine. There's no need anymore now to escape anything after the php-function json_encode does it job.

I believe now that .html is a reserved word in jQuery, so if you want to use parseJSON don't feed it a json with a key named "html".

Answer (score 3):

What you posted is already JSON, no need to parse it.  Example:

```
var data = {"html":"form is NOT valid<form id=\"articleform\" enctype=\"application\/x-www-form-urlencoded\" method=\"post\" action=\"\"><dl class=\"zend_form\">\n<dt id=\"title-label\">&nbsp;<\/dt>\n<dd id=\"title-element\">\n<input type=\"text\" name=\"title\" id=\"title\" value=\"Artikel K\"><\/dd>\n<dt id=\"articleFormSubmitted-label\">&nbsp;<\/dt>\n<dd id=\"articleFormSubmitted-element\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"articleFormSubmitted\" value=\"1\" id=\"articleFormSubmitted\"><\/dd>\n<dt id=\"submit-label\">&nbsp;<\/dt><dd id=\"submit-element\">\n<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Bewaar artikel\" onclick=\"this.value='Bezig...';\"><\/dd><\/dl><\/form><script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\t $(\"#articleform\").submit(function(){\n $.post(\"\/admin\/ajax\/contenttree\/node\/9\/ajaxtarget\/ajaxContainer\", $(\"#articleform\").serialize(), function(html){$(\"#ajaxContainer\").html(html);} );\n\t\t return false;\n\t });\n\n <\/script>","newNodeName":""};

alert(data.html);
alert(data.newNodeName);
```

Am I missing something other piece?, let me know if I'm not understanding correctly.

**Update:** Change your ajax method to use the native `$.ajax` support for this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/admin/ajax/contenttree/node/" + (node.id).replace("node_", ""),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        alert("succes");
        $("#ajaxContainer").html(data.html);
      }
    });
```

Comment: alert(data.html) is giving "undefined". The data-variable is filled by a response that i get from the server, i believe it is just a string so i think it has to be parsed to use it.  If I use "{"html":"test","newNodeName":""}" as input for the parseJSON-function than after the parsing data.html is filled correctly with "test".

Comment: @murze - You need to do `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);`, is this the case, or literally what's in the question?

Comment: @murze - `$.ajax` handles this natively, just add `dataType` like my updated answer.  Also be aware there's a [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method that makes this even cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting with your excerpt that works and then slowing adding back text from the parts that don't work until you find out which bit is causing trouble. The [JSON syntax](http://json.org) is very, very simple, I would be surprised if jQuery had issues with it.

I wondered about your "script" tags and "function" (thinking: "I wonder if those are triggering an exploit protection or something?") but a quick check with jQuery 1.4.1 said that wasn't it.

**Edit**

The problem lies elsewhere, the following works with 1.4.1 or 1.4.2 (didn't work with 1.3.2, but that's because 1.3.2 doesn't have `jQuery.parseJSON` — smacks head). Walk through your code with a debugger and inspect your `data` variable to see what it contains.

Test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    $(document).ready(pageInit);

    function pageInit() {
        $('#btnGo').click(go);
    }

    function go() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                alert("obj.html = " + obj.html);
            }
        });
    }
})();
</script>
</head>
<body><div>
<input type='button' id='btnGo' value='Go'>
</div></body>
</html>
```

test.json:

```
{"html":"form is NOT valid<form id=\"articleform\" enctype=\"application\/x-www-form-urlencoded\" method=\"post\" action=\"\"><dl class=\"zend_form\">\n<dt id=\"title-label\">&nbsp;<\/dt>\n<dd id=\"title-element\">\n<input type=\"text\" name=\"title\" id=\"title\" value=\"Artikel K\"><\/dd>\n<dt id=\"articleFormSubmitted-label\">&nbsp;<\/dt>\n<dd id=\"articleFormSubmitted-element\">\n<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"articleFormSubmitted\" value=\"1\" id=\"articleFormSubmitted\"><\/dd>\n<dt id=\"submit-label\">&nbsp;<\/dt><dd id=\"submit-element\">\n<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Bewaar artikel\" onclick=\"this.value='Bezig...';\"><\/dd><\/dl><\/form><script type=\"text\/javascript\">\n\t $(\"#articleform\").submit(function(){\n $.post(\"\/admin\/ajax\/contenttree\/node\/9\/ajaxtarget\/ajaxContainer\", $(\"#articleform\").serialize(), function(html){$(\"#ajaxContainer\").html(html);} );\n\t\t return false;\n\t });\n\n <\/script>","newNodeName":""}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
alert('start');
data=data.replace('\','\\');
alert(data);
test= jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(test.html);
alert('stop');
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to the problem! Or at least the origin of the problem.

The problem is caused by the "<" and ">" characters. As soon as i try to pass along those characters, the parseJSON-function fails.

Is there a way to allow those characters?

I've already tried to add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to the code that is generating the ajax-response.

Comment: escape them to &gt; and &lt; ?

Comment: i've tried that, but than the piece of html that i'm trying to insert into page is displayed literaly and not processed as html.

Comment: Characters < and > are not the problem, check my answer please.